# Azure CLI - Get newest package from a view (az artifacts universal download)?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-cli, azure-artifacts, azure-devops-extensions, azure-cli2

Using `az artifacts universal download`, how can I download the latest package under a specific view in a feed, e.g. @Prerelease?

I can't seem to find any [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/ext/azure-devops/artifacts/universal?view=azure-cli-latest#ext-azure-devops-az-artifacts-universal-download) on how to specify the view

**Edit - Requests:**

User Voice Request:
https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/idea/1195670/azure-cli-extensions-support-for-specifying-releas.html

Github Issue:
https://github.com/Azure/azure-cli-extensions/issues/2330

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add the View to the feed specified:

e.g. --feed "Contoso@TheView"

Answer (score 1):

I am afraid it is not yet supported to download package under a specific view in the feed. There is not a parameter to specify the view.

You have to find the package's latest version under a specific view in the UI page. And download the package by specifying the version.

You can also [submit a user voice](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/idea/post.html?space=21) to Microsoft development team. Hope they will consider supporting this feature in the future sprint.

Answer (score 1):

I just opened the documentation and you can put

version: '*.*.*'

and get the latest artifact

Comment: True, but that does not take view promotions into account...

Comment: Can confirm this works.

Answer (score 0):

It does not seem to support downloading packages from the UI at the moment, you can only download using [Azure CLI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/artifacts/quickstarts/universal-packages?view=azure-devops&tabs=azuredevops#download-a-universal-package).

> You must use the Azure CLI to download the package. Azure DevOps
> doesn't support direct HTTP/HTTPS download links or other ways to
> download the package.

You can put forward your suggestion [here](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/idea/495533/download-universal-package-trough-api.html), or vote on it.

Answer (score 0):

full task:

```
- task: UniversalPackages@0
  displayName: Download Universal Package
  inputs:
   command: download
   vstsFeed: "my-project/my-feed-name@Release"
   vstsFeedPackage: "my-package"
   vstsPackageVersion: '*' # download latest version
   downloadDirectory: $(Build.SourcesDirectory)
```

You can test all this locally ([doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/artifacts/quickstarts/universal-packages?view=azure-devops&tabs=Windows#download-a-universal-package)):

az artifacts universal download --organization "https://dev.azure.com/my-org-name" --feed "my-feed-name@Release" --project "my-project" --scope project --name "my-package" --version "*" --path "C:\Projects"

az artifacts universal publish --organization "https://dev.azure.com/my-org-name" --feed "my-feed-name" --project "my-project" --scope project --name "my-package" --version "0.0.3" --path "C:\Projects"

To promote to a view you can use the UI too.