Cannot find the package using azure universal download
Why I'm always having the following error:
Cannot find the package 'name' in feed 'name@Local'

When trying to download artifact using universal download with the command:

az artifacts universal download --organization
"https://myorganisation.visualstudio.com/" --project="myproject"
--scope project --feed "myfeed@Local" --name "PackageName" --version "1.0.0-Release.20240616.5" --path .

The package exist in the feed and also the version.
I did the az login first
It works with the Package Manager Console in Visual Studio using this command:

Install-Package PackageName -version 1.0.0-Release.20240616.5



Ensure the type of your target package is Universal Package.



Go to your package's Overview page. Copy the command and then run it in a pipeline to eliminate the possible impact of local cache.


pool:
  vmImage: windows-latest

steps:
- task: CmdLine@2
  inputs:
    script: |
      az artifacts universal download ...
  env:
    AZURE_DEVOPS_EXT_PAT: $(System.AccessToken)


No the parameter --feed "myfeed@Local" is correct. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/66143874/137511

Hi @Vincent, sorry for not noticing this before. I have updated the answer above to help narrow down the issue. Ensure that you are trying to download a universal package using az artifacts universal download. This CLI can't be used to download other type of package.
